# Custom control event handeler

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I have populated a flowLayoutPanel with my custom control and subscribe to the MouseDown event of the controls. How do I create EventArgs to have assess to the custom control properties...

```
        for(int i = 0; i < fileInfoArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myViewerArray[i] = new SubstanceViewer(fileInfoArray[i]);
            myViewerArray[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(myViewerArray_MouseDown);

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(substanceViewerArray[i]);
        }
```

so I can have access to my controls properties...

```
    private void myViewerArray_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = [myControl?].info
    }
```

Comment: Cast `sender` to the type of your control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `sender`:

```
private void myViewerArray_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var myControl = sender as SubstanceViewer;
    richTextBox1.Text = myControl.info;
}
```